# How do I generate a unique link that will load a session with certain docs available to the client?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Sorry for the bad phrasing.

Essentially, I want to be able to generate a link to a page, which will load a session of certain docs.

For example, `Links.find()` returns to Client A `Links.find({clientName:"A"})`. Now Client A wants to send this series of elements to his friend, and wants to do so by sending him a link which loads a client instance that can see `Links.find({clientName"A"})`.

Any input at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [Iron Router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) to your project. Then create a route that puts the relevant query into the URL, for example (in a client-loaded JavaScript file):

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('client', {
    path: '/client/:_clientName',
    before: function () {
      this.subscribe('client', this.params._clientName).wait();
    }
  }
}
```

Then a URI like http://yourapp.com/client/A would cause the *client* template to render (by default it uses the same name as the route name, unless you specify a different name) subscribing to the *client* subscription using "A" as the subscription parameter. This would be paired on the server side with:

```
Meteor.publish('client', function (clientName) {
  // Clients is a Meteor collection
  return Clients.find({clientName: clientName});
});
```

So that's how to process links after they've been generated. As for creating them, just work backwards: what query parameters are you passing to your subscription (that in turn get put into the `find()` call to MongoDB)? Identify each of them and write some code that adds them to an appropriate URI—in this case, your function would simply concatenate "http://yourapp.com/client/" with *clientName,* in this case "A". Obviously much-more-complicated routes/URIs and queries are possible, for example http://yourapp.com/events/2012-01-01/2012-12-31 with an Iron Router route `path` of `/events/:_fromDate/:_toDate` and so on.

Comment: This is a very clear, and very well written guide to the problem. Thank you.